# Testing for unset variables in a for loop

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've written a script which parses a file and sets variables according to a fixed width within the file.

I then want to check each variable and, if it's a blank field, set to "0". A simple variation of this would be:

```
one=1  
two=""  
three=3  
four=""  

for num in $one $two $three $four  
do  
   echo num is $num  
done
```

gives me an output of:

```
num is 1   
num is 3
```

What I want to do is code for `if $two is null then two=0`.

How can I do that?

Comment: WARNING:  Drive-by question.  OP created his (or her) account, asked this question 18 minutes later, and disappeared two minutes earlier (? question asked Dec 9 at 15:30; user Last seen Dec 9 at 15:28), apparently without taking the Tour.

Answer (score 1):

You want the -z comparison operator
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

```
if [ -z $two ]; then   ## or [ -z $num ] to test them all 
    two=0
fi
echo "num is $num"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn’t make a lot of sense.  First of all, if you say

```
one=1
two=""
three=3
four=""

for num in $one $two $three $four
do
    ︙
```

then the `for` statement is interpreted as

```
for num in 1  3
```

and so there are only two iterations, with `num` equal to `1` and `3`. 
If you want to have four iterations,
with `num` equal to `1`, (null), `3` and (null), then you need to say

```
for num in "$one" "$two" "$three" "$four"
```

You should quote shell variable references
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

So,

```
for num in "$one" "$two" "$three" "$four"
do
    echo "num is $num"
done
```

will result in

```
num is 1
num is 
num is 3
num is
```

Now, if you want the results to say `1`, `0`, `3`, `0`,
it’s a simple matter of saying

```
for num in "$one" "$two" "$three" "$four"
do
    if [ "$num" = "" ]
    then
        num=0
    fi
    echo "num is $num"
done
```

Note that

- You must have whitespace before and after the `[`,
- You must have whitespace before and after the `=`,
- You must have whitespace before the `]`
  (and after it, if there’s anything else after it), and
- `fi` is `if` spelled backwards.

But your question title mentions “unset variables”. 
`two` and `four` are ***set*** to a blank string;
`five` and `six` (and `orange`, `pumpkin`, `tiger`,
and a quasi-infinite list of other potential variable names)
are ***unset***.  There’s a difference. 
If *that* is what you’re interested in,
you need to ask a different question, because, if you do

```
for num in "$one" "$two" "$three" "$four" "$five" "$six" "$orange" "$pumpkin" "$tiger"
do
    ︙
```

then it will be impossible to distinguish the `five`, `six`, `orange`,
`pumpkin`, and `tiger`, iterations from the `two` and `four` iterations —
`num` will be set to a blank string in all seven cases. 
You would need to test the `$four` and `$five` (etc.) variables directly.

P.S. Don’t ask a new question; do a search. 
This has been answered before.